# linq query that selects any object in the model

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

**Edit** 
To understand what i am trying to do i will give an example 
Suppose you used entity framework to generate multiple tables. Now you have MyDbEntities with objects (client, user, product, singer [attributes don't matter]). Now you create a method. This method gets an object as a parameter + MyDbEntities. The object would be a client, user, product, singer. In this method you have a query that given the object would return a list of that object. I am trying to create this method but i am still trying either with linq or sql but in vain so far 

**Update** 
I tried this, it works, but not the way i want it to. to understand me check the code below.

```
ViewBag.ok = LibMethods.get_all(MyDbEntities, "Client"); //Params = Entity & String
```

this how i can my method below is my method

```
public static Object get_all (MyDbEntitiesce, String given_entity_type)
    {
        if (given_entity_type.Equals("Client"))
        {
            var get_all = from clt in ce.Client
                      select clt;

            return get_all.ToList().First();
        }
        else if (given_entity_type.Equals("Product"))
        {
            var get_all = from pdt in ce.Product
                      select pdt;

            return get_all.ToList().First();
        }

        return null;
    }
```

As you can see this method checks the object given and creates and returns a list of objects of that given_entity_type. here i return the first element just because i am doing this for tests. 
now suppose that i add a new object to `MyDbEntities` & call it `Developer` i would have to update that method but i don't want to do that i want something generic that would work on any object i give it that exists in `MyDbEntities`. that's what i mean by generic/dynamic.

Comment: What is the *one single question* you want to ask? If you figured that out, please show the code to clarify it. Your current question is incomprehensible.

Comment: i have genarated entites that contain multiple objects (client, product, etc...) i am trying to create a method that given the object (client or product or whichever) would return a list of that object

Answer (score 0):

Would the [OfType](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb360913.aspx) query be what you want? I'm not sure I clearly understand your question, but this query will filter the list of objects by the given type.

Comment: no i have multiple objects & the linq query doesn't accept an Object it requires a specific object in the entity like DbEntity.Client what i want to do is a generic query like DbEntity.Object but it doesn't work so i am trying  to find a way around without having to change the code if i add/delete objects in the entity

Answer (score 0):

Although I do not understand what your ultimate goal is, I would suggest that you look into [DbSet.Set()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg696460(v=vs.113).aspx) method:

You can then use it like this `Context.Set<Singer>()` or `Context.Set<Client>()` depending on your target table.

That is the most generic you can get. Try showing more Code to make your scenario more clear.